# Twitter share image with text, toast "Image Could Not Be Loaded"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, twitter, share

I am getting the toast **`Image Could Not Be Loaded`** when I trying and attach an image URL to a tweet. I have changed type but still not working.

**My intent code:**

```
String imageUrl="http://www.cyclesoon.com/admin/assets/img/rideimages/1499161893615.jpg";
Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Join ride");
tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imageUrl));
tweetIntent.setType("image/png");

PackageManager packManager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoList = packManager.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

boolean resolved = false;
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolvedInfoList) {
    if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.twitter.android")) {
        tweetIntent.setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
        resolved = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (resolved) {
    startActivity(tweetIntent);
} else {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + urlEncode("")));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Any solution appreciates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you see the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/compose-tweets), there is a line which says The image Uri should be a file Uri (i.e. file://absolute_path scheme) to a local file. So yes, Image should be on your device. – by  **Mohammed Atif**